# How to add a lightened layer to a darkened image to make it look the same as before

Tags: css

So here is the problem. I'm dealing with my cropper component and it looks like below:
[cropper component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxsGI.png)
[original picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s6bq.jpg)
I added a ::after to the img element and set its CSS as `background-color: #000; opacity: .5`.And I also set the cropper zone's CSS as `background-color: #fff; opacity: .3`.As u see, the image displayed in the cropper zone doesn't look the same as it was before, it just get brighter, but still unsaturated. How could I set the ::after and the cropper zone's css to make them neutralize so that the part of image in the cropper zone could display as there's no filter on it?

Here is my code:
React Component:

```
<div className='Cropper__editZone'>
  <img src={url} ref={img} className='Cropper__image' onLoad={imgOnLoad} />
  <div
    className='Cropper__zone'
    ref={target}
    style={{ top: 0, left: 0, right: `${right}px`, bottom: `${bottom}px` }}
    onMouseDown={moveZone}
  >
    <div
      className='Cropper__zone__rightTop'
      onMouseDown={e => {
        mountEvent(e, 'rightTop');
      }}
    ></div>
    <div
      className='Cropper__zone__leftTop'
      onMouseDown={e => {
        mountEvent(e, 'leftTop');
      }}
    ></div>
    <div
      className='Cropper__zone__rightBottom'
      onMouseDown={e => {
        mountEvent(e, 'rightBottom');
      }}
    ></div>
    <div
      className='Cropper__zone__leftBottom'
      onMouseDown={e => {
        mountEvent(e, 'leftBottom');
      }}
    ></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SASS：

```
.Cropper__editZone
    position: relative
    &::after
      content: ''
      position: absolute
      top: 0
      bottom: 0
      left: 0
      right: 0
      background-color: #000
      opacity: .5
      z-index: 1
    img
      box-sizing: border-box
      display: block
      max-width: 40vw
      max-height: 50vh
    .Cropper__zone
      box-sizing: border-box
      cursor: move
      border: 1px solid white
      position: absolute
      z-index: 2
      background-color: white
      opacity: .1
      .Cropper__zone__rightTop, .Cropper__zone__leftTop, .Cropper__zone__rightBottom, .Cropper__zone__leftBottom
        border: 3px solid $dark
        width: 0
        height: 0
        position: absolute
        z-index: 5
      .Cropper__zone__rightTop
        cursor: ne-resize
        top: -3px
        right: -3px
      .Cropper__zone__leftTop
        cursor: nw-resize
        top: -3px
        left: -3px
      .Cropper__zone__rightBottom
        bottom: -3px
        cursor: se-resize
        right: -3px
      .Cropper__zone__leftBottom
        cursor: sw-resize
        bottom: -3px
        left: -3px
```

Comment: Hey there Mingyang! Welcome to stackoverflow!
Can we please see your code? JSFiddle or codepen?

Comment: @Jessica Of course! I have just updated my question with some code added.